# Run a list of bash commands from a string in python

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu

My program is a text editor for bash scripts. For the run option I need to obtain all the commands typed in the textbox and execute them as if they were an entire script (the option of writing the string in a file and then execute it is also possible). Also, I need to pass some arguments (a string in the entry box), and obtain stderr and stdout if the user wants it (checkboxes).

My program looks like this:

[interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7j14.png)

I know how to obtain data from all graphic components, my big problem is that I'm not sure what to do: subprocess.call, subprocess.popen, os.system, etc. There are a lot of options. I need to use just one command whatever they write on the text box: pipes, simple commands, argument printing, etc.

It is desirable too that nothing is shown in my console.

Thank you for helping! Every idea is welcome!

I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please narrow your question down to a specific coding problem that would be on-topic for this site.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262527/how-to-ask-a-good-question-when-im-not-sure-what-im-looking-for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `subprocess`. It was intended to replace other methods of running external processes. Rather than repeat the documentation, I will try to summarize:

In Python 2.7 you have several options:

`subprocess.call` : runs the command, returning the returncode

`subprocess.check_call` : raise exception if nonzero returncode is returned

`subprocess.check_output` : run command, returning output as a string

In Python 3.5+, the interface was simplified and you can simply use `subprocess.run()`, which returns a `subprocess.CompletedProcess` object from which you can access stdout, stderr, return code, etc.

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html